# django dumpdata empty array

Tags: python, django

I am fairly new to django and I am using it to make a website for an online game.  The game already has it's own auth stuff so I am using that as a custom auth model for django.

I created a new app called 'account' to put this stuff in and added the models.  I added the router and enabled it in the settings and everything works good, I can log in from the admin site and do stuff.

Now I am also trying to learn TDD, so I need to dump the auth database to a fixture.
When I run `./manage.py dumpdata account` i get an empty array back.  There aren't any errors or any trace back what so ever, just an empty array.  I've fiddled with it the best I can but I can't seem to find what the issue is.

Here are some relevant settings.

### Database

```
DATABASES = {  
    'default': {  
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',  
        'NAME': 'censored',  
        'USER': 'censored',  
        'PASSWORD': 'censored',  
        'HOST': 'localhost',  
        'PORT': '',  
    },    
    'auth_db': {  
        'ENGINE': 'mysql_pymysql',  
        'NAME': 'censored',  
        'USER': 'censored',  
        'PASSWORD': 'censored',  
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',  
        'PORT': '3306'  
    }  
}
```

### Router

```
class AccountRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    account application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read account models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'account':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write account models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'account':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the account app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'account' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'account':
                return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        """
        Make sure the account app only appears in the 'auth_db'
        database.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'account':
            return False
        return None
```

### Django Settings

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['account.router.AccountRouter']
```

I am really at a loss for what to try, any help or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also had the same issue, you need to specify the correct database. For example, given your code:

```
$ ./manage.py dumpdata --database=auth_db account
```

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem. Creating an empty file called `models.py` solved the problem for me. Check if you have such a file in your app catalog and if not - create one.

Comment: I don't understand this solution. How can there be data in the app in the first place, if there isn't already a `models.py` file? This is the second time I find this proposed answer, but it seems like there is something missing in it. Where should this new `models.py` file reside?

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure the model goes correct. if the model has an error, the `./manage.py dumpdata` command will keep silent while running and output `[]`. So the suggestion is to run the models' code in `./manage.py shell` and the target data exists, for example:

`from account.models import Account
    print Account.objects.all()[:1]`

- Make sure `./manage.py dumpdata` can find the targe model. Django finds models via `{APP_NAME}.models`, if you place your models in directory `account/models/`, import your models in `account/models/__init__.py`, for example:`from profile import Profile`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252228/django-dumpdata-output-is-empty#answer-26483998) in another Stackoverflow thread helped me more than the answers above: the issue was indeed related to a misconfiguration of my router, more specifically to `allow_migrate` which should return `True` for the given model, the given app and the given database.

I believe this is due to [this line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py#L166) (Django source code on Github) of the command `dumpdata`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an app structure where `models.py` is not in the app root dir, just add a blank one in the app root dir

Comment: How is this different from the already existing answer by Tomasz?

Comment: It clarifies that the `models.py` could be in the app but in a different place other than the app root dir. I would have made it as a comment in response to Teekin's question under Tomasz's answer but I don't have enough reputation to do that