# Django dumpdata output is empty

Tags: django, postgresql, django-manage.py, dumpdata

we have a Django 1.4.5 project with a PostgreSQL 9.3 backend. Unfortunately we are facing the problems when attempting to create fixtures for one of the apps (which is called `sddb`).

The database is full of objects that belong to `sddb` app:

```
(venv)[root@dl380p1 team112]# ./manage.py shell
>>> from sddb.models.media import Metadata
>>> len(Metadata.objects.all())
22916
```

However the `dumpdata` output is empty:

```
(venv)[root@dl380p1 team112]# ./manage.py dumpdata sddb
[]
```

Explicit pointing of database (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19789666/2361497)) didn't help:

```
(venv)[root@dl380p1 team112]# ./manage.py dumpdata --database=project_test sddb
[]
```

For the other apps `dumpdata` is working properly:

```
(venv)[root@dl380p1 team112]# ./manage.py dumpdata reports | wc -c
239811
```

I don't want to use the entire table dumps (`pgdump`) due to obvious reasons. Hope to find right solution here.

Comment: wish [this questhion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252228/django-dumpdata-output-is-empty) be helpful for you

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue already?

Comment: @javidazac I don't use Django anymore...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it was related to DB routers. Just make sure that a router processes correctly the `allow_migrate` method (one of routers should return `True` or True-like value by default).
See more examples here: [Django Multiple databases Examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example)

Comment: The "Multiple database example" does not help in the case where you have multiple databases for a single app. Some models in my app are in one SQLite, while others are in another. I have not been able to figure out how the `allow_migrate` function needs to work in order to solve this issue, right now when I try to use `dumpdata` with this app I get and output of `[]`, nothing is dumped. However all other aspects of the app appear to be working fine.

Comment: if would be helpful if you could provide a working example for `allow_migrate`, because mine looks exactly like what is shown in the docs linked there and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have multiple databases but still I was getting empty fixtures when dumped.

I had to add a separate empty models.py in my app to get the data dumped.